# Kusto Query to update table column type with out impacting data

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I have a kusto table with id:int and name:string fields with data in it. I am trying to alter table schema types for id: int to id:long. I tried the below but it throws the below error. I also tried .alter instead of .alter-merge but no luck. What is the procedure to update Kusto table column type for existing table with data and without disturbing the current data?

```
.alter-merge table mytable
(Id: long, Name: string)
```

Error:
'Alter table does not support column data type change for existing columns (Id). Current type=I32, requested type=I64'.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the process you should follow to achieve what you want:

1. Create a new table named `OldTable` with the updated schema
2. Create a function named `Table` (should be exact name as your original table) that will return `union (OldTable | project id = tolong(id), name), (Table | project id = tolong(id), name)` - this way, whenever someone writes `Table`, he'll call the function that will return data from both tables in the correct schema
3. Swap `Table` and `OldTable`
4. When the data in the `OldTable` table ages out (at the end of the retention period), it will become empty, and you'll have to first delete the `Table` function, then the `OldTable` table